# Calculation not being performe properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I have the following code that is converting characters entered in an input field into other characters (namely, entering an e or and E and converting it to a 3, likewise for a t or T into a 7).
I am also calculating the percentage of the characters that were converted, but my calculation is not being performed properly and was wondering if someone can help with this.
For example, if someone enters in a string like 373, it will not convert the characters (as expected), but the number of converted characters will be 3 when they should be 0 instead.

```js
function ReplaceChars() {

  var json         = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("registration"));
  var characters   = json['charsEntered'];
  var total        = "";
  var convertedPct = 0;

  const result = characters
      .replaceAll(/e|E/g,"3")
      .replaceAll(/t|T/g,"7")

  total = characters.length;

  let x = Number((result.match(/3|7/g)||[]).length);
  let y = Number(total);

  convertedPct      = (x/y)*100
  roundedPercentage = convertedPct.toFixed(2);

  $("#charsConverted").val(result);
  $("#convertedChars").val(x);
  $("#totalChars").val(y);
  $("#pctChars").val(roundedPercentage + "%");
}
```

Comment: You need to check for the characters before converting not after.

Comment: 2 options. 1. Read how many 3-s and 7-s are before conversion, and then read how many are there after conversion. after - before = changed. Or you iterate over the words and check them index by index. If value in a[index] !== b[index] then it changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function when replacing characters that would also count

```js
  let totalReplacements = 0;

  characters
    .replace(/e|E/g, () => {
      totalReplacements ++; 
      return '3';
    })
    .replace(/t|T/g, () => {
      totalReplacements ++; 
      return '7'
    })
```

Now totalRepalcements will hold the total number of replacements that have been done.

```js
  convertedPct      = (totalReplacements / characters.length) * 100
  roundedPercentage = convertedPct.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're matching the result, whose matched values may be a mix of changed or unchanged characters.  Matched values in your source will all be changed.

Change: `let x = Number((result.match(/3|7/g)||[]).length);`

To: `let x = (json.charsEntered.match(/[etET]/g)||[]).length;`